# Can I create a Hangout "client" program? (kind of Google TalkAbout)

Tags: google-plus, google-talk, google-hangouts

As stated in the [Google Talk for Developers site](https://developers.google.com/talk/talk_developers_home), you can use the provided APIs to build a client that connects to the Google Talk service.

I would like to know if it's possible (or it will be in the near future) to build a similar client to the google hangouts.

What we pretend is to build something similar to cloud print, that provides printing services to the cloud, but for audio/video streaming: a camera and microphone would replace the
printer.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Talk and all the XMPP stuff is going to be put down soon.

The new Hangouts infrastructure is proprietary. It only has API to integrate Hangouts into web pages and applications, but no API or protocol to create an alternative Hangouts client software.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tdryer/hangups is a library that does exactly that, with a command-line client for Linux.

https://github.com/xmikos/qhangups is a PyQt-based cross-platform app that aims to provide an open-source alternative to the Chrome-based official desktop app. Unfortunately it's not working at the time of posting, but the author is investigating the issue.